# Enable Google Storage purchase on a Google Apps domain

Tags: google-workspace

I can't seem to find how to enable this anywhere in the admin panel. Whenever I want to add paid storage for the Docs, it says it's not enabled on my domain.

How and where do I enable this?

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer.

You have to enable 'User Managed Storage' in the control panel. Under 'Organizations and Users' then 'Services'

That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

To enable Individual storage:

Go to: admin.google.com
Select: More Controls
Select: More Google Apps
Select Filter-Icon in upper-right...deselect "Show top featured services"
Find and Enable: Individual Storage

Once active...user goes to:
https://www.google.com/settings/storage